# How to validate email (internationally)

Tags: php, email-validation

I am creating contact form and there I have input field, type email.
In the future, I am planing to save this email and all other data into database.
Therefore I have a question on how to validate that email properly in PHP?

-It has to accept utf-8 and all international individual characters that email can have.

For now, I have made two different email validations.

First one is made by using filter_var() but this one doesn't allow international characters to be used. (Therefore I have removed it.)

Second, I have used custom regex  '/^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+.[^\s@]+$/ui'  and this one is allowing use of international characters but it also allows '/* and other characters which are threat for possible SQL injection.

I am also aware, that there is an option to send email to a user to verify that email but I am wondering, is there any verification method which I can use to validate email internationally and to prevent SQL injection?

Maybe encrypting/decrypting email?
Maybe PDO should be enough?

Comment: Preventing SQL injection doesn't happen by ensuring you have a valid email address, it happens by using [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) with [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: these are two different problems...email validation is actually pretty complicated if you want to support all valid emails per specs (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)). For SQL Injection prevention, you should use parameterized queries and prepared statements ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php))

Comment: This means that PDO should secure it, right?

Comment: _"This means that PDO should secure it, right?"_ Only if you use it correctly. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone is looking for an answer to this question, Now after two years of working as a developer I would agree with Alex Howansky comment:

Preventing SQL injection doesn't happen by ensuring you have a valid email address, it happens by using prepared statements with bound parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Regex to validate non-standard email address:

```
^([\p{L}\.\-\d]+)@([\p{L}\-\.\d]+)((\.(\p{L})      {2,63})+)$
```

Original source [How to validate non-english (UTF-8) encoded email address in Javascript and PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219848/how-to-validate-non-english-utf-8-encoded-email-address-in-javascript-and-php)

Comment: I have tried to use this regex in php but id doesn't work?